# Randominze the time between my slideshow using Orbit

Tags: jquery, orbit

I'm using the Jquery Orbit for my image slideshow but I want the pictures to be on a random timer. I'm not very jquery savvy so if you could help me out I would appreciate it. Here is what I have code wise so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#newest').orbit();
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To call your slideshow, use the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function generateRandomInteger(minNumber, maxNumber, minDigits, maxDigits) {
        var num, digits;
        do {
            num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber - minNumber)) + minNumber;
            digits = Math.abs(num).toString().length;
        } while (digits > maxDigits || digits < minDigits);
        return num;
    }
    $(function() {
        var randomSpeed = generateRandomInteger(2000, 10000, 4, 5);
        $('#newest').orbit({
            timer: true,             
            advanceSpeed: randomSpeed
        });
    });
</script>
```

On this line: `var randomSpeed = generateRandomInteger(2000, 10000, 4, 5);`
those numbers are `generateRandomInteger(minNumber, maxNumber, minNumDigits, maxNumDigits);`